# Will a 2 by 2 quadratic form be negative definitive if it has repeated eigenvalues which are negative?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Say we have the quadratic form 
$$ f = x^T Q x \\ Q = \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$ which has repeated eigenvalues 
$\lambda = -1$. Will the quadratic form be negative definitive? If yes then why?

Comment: What is the definition of negative definite quadratic form? Does $Q$ satisfy it?

Comment: Negative definitive is when the quadratic form is < 0 for any non zero vector x.

Comment: Let $x = (x_1,x_2)^T$ be a vector. Then $f(x)= -x_1^2-x_2^2$ which is negative if $x$ is not the vector $(0,0)$, and is $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let any vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\|x\|_2> 0$then
$$x^TQx = \langle x, Qx\rangle = \langle x, -I_2x\rangle = \langle x,-x\rangle  = -\langle x,x\rangle=- \|x\|^2_2<0,$$
where $I_2$ is the $2 \times 2$ [identity matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix), $\|\cdot\|_2$ the [euclidian norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm) and $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ the [euclidian inner product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Algebraic_definition).
It follows that the matrix $Q$ is negative definite.

Note that from the definition of negative definite matrix proposed by [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeDefiniteMatrix.html), just the fact that the eigenvalues are $-1$ is enough to conclude. However if you use the definition of [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Negative-definite) then you have to do the above computation to show that $Q$ is negative definite.

Comment: Wait, sorry but i dont understand this, can you explain a bit more. Thank you.

Comment: @CodeBreaker sure :), what is unclear to you?

Comment: All good now. Thank you.